# Passing multiple parameters to Prism's EventAggregator

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

I'm using Prism's EventAggregator for loosely coupled communication between my module's ViewModels. I have have several properties (e.g. FirstName, LastName) in **ViewModelA** which need to update properties in **ViewModelB** when their values change. My current solution involves:

**ViewModelA** publishes an Event with the new value for FirstName as the payload:

```
 public string FirstName
    {
        get {return firstName;}
        set 
        {
            this.firstName = value;
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<PatientDetailsEvent>().Publish(firstName);
        }
    }
```

**ViewModelB** is subscribed to the Event and changes its FirstName property accordingly:

```
public PatientBannerViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<PatientDetailsEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateBanner, ThreadOption.UIThread);
    }

    public void UpdateBanner(string firstName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }
```

This works fine for a single property. It doesn't work for multiple, different properties because **ViewModelB** has no idea what property has changed on **ViewModelA** . ViewModelB knows what the new value is, but it doesn't know which of its properties to update.

I could create separate Events for each property but this seems repetitive. It seems cleaner to just use one Event. Ideally, when publishing the Event, ViewModelA should tell ViewModelB which property has changed. How can I do this?

Comment: OK, I have found the answer to my question in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7285056/896265). I will post a specific answer to my question after 8 hours have elapsed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answer to my question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285056/896265). [This blog post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/) by Rachel Lim is also helpful.

What we need is for **ViewModelA** (the publisher) to tell **ViewModelB** (the subscriber) two pieces of information:

1. What property has changed on **ViewModelA**
2. What is the new value of this property

We need to communicate 2 pieces of information (*i.e. properties*) but Prism's EventAggregator takes only one parameter, the `payload`. This is the problem.

To pass multiple pieces of information (*properties*) via the EventAggregator you can publish an instance of a class which defines these properties as the EventAggregator's `payload`. I called this class `PatientDetailsEventParameters` and it defines two properties:

```
public class PatientDetailsEventParameters
{
    public string PatientProperty { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I created this class in an Infrastructure assembly (the same place where I define my Events) which all my other assemblies have a reference to.

You can then publish an instance of this class as the payload (instead of a string which holds only 1 value). This allows for multiple parameters to be passed into the payload.

```
public string FirstName
    {
        get 
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.firstName = value;
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<PatientDetailsEvent>().Publish(new PatientDetailsEventParameters() {Value = firstName, PatientProperty = "firstName"});
        }
    }
```

You can see here that a new instance of my `PatientDetailsEventParameters` is created when the `PatientDetailsEvent` is published. The two properties `Value` and `PatientProperty` are also set. `PatientProperty` is a string which tells **ViewModelB** (i.e. the subscriber) what property has changed. `Value` is the new value of the property  that has changed.